# Textured quad rendering in pixel stripes

Tags: directx, hlsl, windows-api-code-pack

I have the following `.fx` file:

```
Texture2D texture2d;

SamplerState linearSampler
{
  Filter = MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
  AddressU = Clamp;
  AddressV = Clamp;
};

struct VS_IN
{
  float4 pos : POSITION;
  float3 uvq : TEXCOORD0;
};

struct PS_IN
{
  float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
  float3 uvq : TEXCOORD0;
};

PS_IN VS(VS_IN input)
{
  PS_IN output = (PS_IN)0;

  output.pos = float4(input.pos.xyz, 1.0);
  output.uvq = input.uvq;

  return output;
}

float4 PS(PS_IN input) : SV_Target
{
  return texture2d.Sample(linearSampler, input.uvq.xy);
}

technique10 Render
{
  pass P0
  {
    SetVertexShader(CompileShader(vs_4_0, VS()));
    SetGeometryShader(NULL);
    SetPixelShader(CompileShader(ps_4_0, PS()));
  }
}
```

(Note: `uvq` is `float3` for a reason, `q` will later be used but it's just ignored now).

When I use this effect to texture map a quad (texture image to the left), I get the rendering to the right: the pixels come from the texture all right but they are rather strangely sampled and repeated in stripes.

[image: texture and rendering]

The co-ordinates are nothing special, the full texture:

```
public Vertex[] vertices = {
  new Vertex() { Position = new D3.Vector4F(-0.7f, -0.5f, 0, 0), UVQ = new D3.Vector3F(0f, 1f, 0) },
  new Vertex() { Position = new D3.Vector4F(-0.4f,  0.6f, 0, 0), UVQ = new D3.Vector3F(0f, 0f, 0) },
  new Vertex() { Position = new D3.Vector4F( 0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 0), UVQ = new D3.Vector3F(1f, 1f, 0) },
  new Vertex() { Position = new D3.Vector4F( 0.3f,  0.9f, 0, 0), UVQ = new D3.Vector3F(1f, 0f, 0) },
};
```

The texture has been read using the `TextureLoader.cs` helper routines as they come in the Code Pack API tutorial.

```
var TextureVariable = DxEffect.GetVariableByName("texture2d").AsShaderResource;
var stream = Application.GetResourceStream(MakePackUri("Resources/image.png"));
TextureVariable.Resource = DXUtil.TextureLoader.LoadTexture(DxDevice, stream.Stream);
```

Input layout is as follows:

```
var layout = new D3D.InputElementDescription[] {
  new D3D.InputElementDescription() { SemanticName = "POSITION", SemanticIndex = 0, Format = GX.Format.R32G32B32A32Float, AlignedByteOffset = 0, InputSlot = 0, InputSlotClass = D3D.InputClassification.PerVertexData, InstanceDataStepRate = 0 },
  new D3D.InputElementDescription() { SemanticName = "TEXCOORD", SemanticIndex = 0, Format = GX.Format.R32G32B32Float, AlignedByteOffset = 16, InputSlot = 0, InputSlotClass = D3D.InputClassification.PerVertexData, InstanceDataStepRate = 0 }
};
var DxPassDesc = DxTechnique.GetPassByIndex(0).Description;
var DxLayout = DxDevice.CreateInputLayout(layout, DxPassDesc.InputAssemblerInputSignature, DxPassDesc.InputAssemblerInputSignatureSize);
DxDevice.IA.InputLayout = DxLayout;

var vertex = new VertexArray();
var DxVertexBufferDescription = new D3D.BufferDescription() { BindingOptions = D3D.BindingOptions.VertexBuffer, CpuAccessOptions = D3D.CpuAccessOptions.None, MiscellaneousResourceOptions = D3D.MiscellaneousResourceOptions.None, Usage = D3D.Usage.Default, ByteWidth = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(vertex) };
IntPtr vertexData = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(vertex));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(vertex, vertexData, false);
var DxVertexBufferInitData = new D3D.SubresourceData() { SystemMemory = vertexData, SystemMemoryPitch = 0, SystemMemorySlicePitch = 0 };
var DxVertices = DxDevice.CreateBuffer(DxVertexBufferDescription, DxVertexBufferInitData);
uint stride = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Vertex));
uint offset = 0;
DxDevice.IA.SetVertexBuffers(0, new D3D.D3DBuffer[] { DxVertices }, new uint[] { stride }, new uint[] { offset });
Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(vertexData);
```

Comment: Seems like the texture coordinates was incorrect, can you paste the code of your program?

Comment: Added to the question now, I forgot to mention it because there was nothing really special about it: the full texture from zero to one, as usual.

Comment: Can you post input layout you use to bind your vertex buffer to the shader? Could come from some invalid stride.

Comment: Added the input layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The maximum texture size seems to be 512 (although descriptions at MS seem to suggest larger values for DX10 Texture2D). Well...